# how to hide/view header view table in iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have static UItableview to hold user form. I added header view in the table to show email validation files  my problem is the header does not show a smooth transition between hiding/show and overlap with the first row
[image]

I want to ask how I can fix the hight of the table header view and does not make it overlap
code

```
@IBOutlet weak var errorView: UIView!

@IBAction func next(_ sender: Any) {
    let newUserEmail = self.txtfEmail.text
    if isValidEmail(newUserEmail!) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "addInventryToNewUser", sender: self)
    }
    else {
        cellemail.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
        cellemail.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor

        let f = errorView.frame;      
           errorView.frame = CGRect(x: f.origin.x, y: f.origin.y, width: f.width, height: 21);
        errorView.isHidden = false

        lblError.text = "❌ Invalid email address."
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to apply some animation for a smooth transition. Here's how:

```
@IBAction func next(_ sender: Any) {
    let newUserEmail = self.txtfEmail.text
    if isValidEmail(newUserEmail!) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "addInventryToNewUser", sender: self)
    }
    else {
        cellemail.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
        cellemail.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
             self.errorView.frame.size.height = 21
        }
        errorView.isHidden = false

        lblError.text = "❌ Invalid email address."
    }
}
```

Comment: and how to hide it after time 5 seconds?

Answer (score 2):

I have no enough reputation to add a comment, but the answer on "how to hide it after 5 seconds?" Is:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5) {
    // your code to hide view here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I will combine the two answer:

```
@IBAction func next(_ sender: Any) {
    let newUserEmail = self.txtfEmail.text
    if isValidEmail(newUserEmail!) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "addInventryToNewUser", sender: self)
    }
    else {
        cellemail.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
        cellemail.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
             self.errorView.frame.size.height = 21
        }

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5) {
    // your code to hide view here
}
        errorView.isHidden = false

        lblError.text = "❌ Invalid email address."
    }
}
```